# How to make chrome.tabs.update works with content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I work on a little extension on Google Chrome, I want to create a new tab, go on the url "sample"+i+".com", launch a content script on this url, update the current tab to "sample"+(i+1)+".com", and launch the same script. I looked the Q&A available on stackoverflow and I google it but I didn't found a solution who works. This is my actually code of background.js (it works), it creates two tabs (i=21 and i=22) and load my content script for each url, when I tried to do a chrome.tabs.update Chrome launchs directly a tab with i = 22  (and the script works only one time) :

```
function extraction(tab) {
for (var i =21; i<23;i++)
    {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'extraction' : 1}, function() {}); //for my content script
        chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://example.com/"+i+".html"}, function() {});
    } 
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {extraction(tab);});
```

If anyone can help me, the content script and manifest.json are not the problem. I want to make that 15000 times so I can't do otherwise.

Thank you.

Comment: It should be possible for you to create a new link element on the page with the required  URL and the click the link.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `chrome.tabs.create` is an async function so you need to create a separate function so that the `i` variable is copied each time:

try this:

```
var func = function(i)
{
        chrome.storage.sync.set({'extraction' : 1}, function() {}); //for my content script
        chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://example.com/"+i+".html"}, function() {});
}

function extraction(tab) {
for (var i =21; i<23;i++)
    {
      func(i);
    } 
}
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {extraction(tab);});
```

Comment: It works but this is not the answer that I look, I want to transform the "chrome.tabs.create" in "chrome.tabs.update" and still launch the content script every time my extension change the url.

Comment: Well if you add 'http ://example.com/*' (with asterisk) to your manifest file then chrome will always embed your script no matter what the url is.

Comment: If I transform chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://example.com/"+i+".html"}, function() {}); in chrome.tabs.update(tab.id,{url: "http://example.com/"+i+".html"}, function() {}); the script works only for the last page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the tab finished loading, and that your content script finished running, before updating the tab to the next url. One way to achieve that would be by sending a message from the content script to the background page. You can include the following in your content script:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage("finished");
```

In your background script you can do the following:

```
var current = 21, end = 23;
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender) {
    if( request == "finished" && current <= end ) {
      chrome.tabs.update( sender.tab.id,
                       {url: "http://example.com/"+current+".html"});
      current++;
    }
  }
);
chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://example.com/"+current+".html"});
```